# Animating appearing/extending strip with gaps

Tags: animation, transparency, path, dynamic-paint, bezier-curves

As i am new to blender i decided to learn by recreating some animations which have some interesting problems, and gain more knowledge about how tv intros are being done, collecting some parody intros to videos. I came across a simple yet troublesome effect , found no answer by googling or getting through tutorials and testing methods on this case led me to nowhere.

https://youtu.be/amyFUdwQc6Y

I attempted to recreate the animation above, especially  the extending/appearing/drawn white strip with "randomly" placed gaps , strip which travels just above surface , casting shadow.

Tried dynamic paint,( with alpha channel) image sequence texture but although effect was very similar, whole invisible strip was casting shadow being Z transparent, in places where white color haven't reached yet.

I tried bezier curves as well(vector mode) but it appears that taper cant profile part in squary way, or maybe i am missing something here.

Shape keys seem to hard way to go , while keeping whole animation of stripe "unrolling" at constant speed.

I tried as well putting an array of planes on the path but it is completely not what i attempt to achieved.

I will edit post and add some pictures tomorrow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few methods that you could use to achieve this, some simpler, some more flexible. The one that follows can give you results similar to what's shown in the video.

First create a curve object that roughly follows your desired path, bevel its corners so you get less distortion on tight curves. In this example I use the great [Curve Fillet Tool](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/bezier-curve-fillet-tool/) addon from the Blender CG Cookie Market (it's a paid extension, but worth the price IMHO), you can also use the [Simple Curves Addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Simple_curves) or just do it manually if you prefer.

[image: Add curve]

Now add a plane object, scale it lengthwise so it's narrowest side is placed along the curve length for better precision. Also scale the other direction to match the desired line thickness. Make sure you apply the scale before proceeding.

Add an *Array* modifier to you plane, and set it to *Fit Curve* and pick the previously created curve. Tick the Option *Merge* to join the arrayed planes.

Now add a *Curve* Modifier on top of it, set it to the same curve and it should distort it along the curve length. Make both the plane and the curve coincide at the same scene coordinate to avoid unwanted distortions.

[image: Plane Array]

Now the magic all comes from a *Build* Modifier, which will make the strip like effect progressively grow along the curve as desired. (Scrub the timeline to see the effect)

[image: Build Modifier]

If you want more control, optionally apply the *Array* and *Curve Modifier* Modifiers only (leaving the *Build* Modifier live) if you later wish to manually adjust the shape of the strip, like different materials along the path, varying width, colors or add gaps, otherwise leave all modifiers live for a more flexible non destructive workflow.

[image: Final Strip]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was closer than i thought but didn't consider applying modifier as a way to model and then put the gaps. Thank you very much again. I gave you an upvote but stackexchange won't let it effect because its my first steps.

Comment: Yes, it's a shame one has to apply the modifiers, I am a strong advocate of fully procedural non destructive workflows, but in this case I figured no other way around it. No problem don't worry about the vote; optionally you may also consider marking it as correct if it did solve you problem

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't done it yet. Yes , it helps a lot.

Comment: And in terms of applying modifiers , i found the way to place gaps (evenly though, at regular inervals) by just applying more array modifiers on top of each other, one for grouping planes, another for grouping groups, and another to fill the curve with that pattern

Comment: Hey that's pretty interesting! With that technique you can even layer several array modifiers with different gaps on top of each other for several different lengths

Comment: Yeah, but then you get black mess with normals (i mean by that overlapping planes , not sure yet what normals exactly are for planes) in render . Hovewer i got the same on radii without using an addon, after applying modifiers i delete overlapping planes in corners and you can get it that way.

Comment: This is very interesting! Do you know if it is possible to change build modifier speed interpolation? I mean, it seems to have a constant velocity, but I'd like to have a smooth interpolation in start/stop position. I have an object following the path and a plane extruding while it moves, but object start and stop moving slowly.

Comment: No, I don't think there is, as far as I know. *Build Modifier* is quite limited in that regard, you can only adjust the *Start* and *Length* parameter. For more advanced control you may use bezier curves with a Start and End bevel offset

Comment: @joaulo it is possible to keyframe those values, which makes it extremely messy and hard to understand but i believe i used this once and this way you possibly can achieve the easing you mention. BTW you can check the result(it supposed to look and sound poor- its parody): [resulting video] (https://youtu.be/r8UXCPNiISw)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos it is possible, but keyframing the starting frame, which is weird way. And i did something similar with bezier curves: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU23kvoXi04, but hard cut-off gaps are impossible unless you use alpha texture prepared to make it look like gaps.