# Blender - road with varying width

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

How to create road that follows curve and has varying width along this curve? Typically I'd make small road segment and use array, then curve but I don't think it allows scaling according to another curve.

Alernative solution would be to try skinning road curve by using Bevel and Taper curves in Object properties and that's kind of what I'd like to achieve but it lacks flexibility of using conventional mesh for road segment.

Something between could use lattice after array, before curve i guess?... But it sounds painful

Comment: Using array and curve you can play with the ''radius" setting for the curve.

Comment: For easy control of width best way really is Taper and Bevel curves, at the expense of control, for more detail you will probably have to do some manual modeling. See if any of these help http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/49651#49651 http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps/63322#63322