# Quad faces along the curve or grease pencil

Tags: bezier-curves, grease-pencil

**Is it possible to generate quad faces along the curve ?**

**Is it possible to generate quad faces along the grease pencil ?**

For example, I set up some bezier curve and on this curve Blender generate connected quad faces uniformely.

I know that grease pencil can do that  for mesh reopology. Is is possible to do that without the mesh?

Black is curve or grease pencil, blue are faces only I want them to be regular (same size) and connected.
[image]

Comment: Is something similar to this what you need https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps/63322#63322 ?

Comment: Like in retopology, I want grease pencil or bezier curve to have connected faces along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since at least Blender version 2.65, the grease pencil has included a "convert" button, one of the options of which was to convert the grease pencil work to a bezier curve. Selecting the bezier curve, and applying the command <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> permits the conversion of the bezier curve to a mesh object. From there it's just a matter of applying standard modeling techniques to convert the edges to quad faces. The following image exemplifying this technique was made by adding a bezier curve to a scene in top orthographic view, selecting all vertices, witching to front orthographic view, and extruding along the z axis.

[[image: enter image description here]]

At some point, changes to the grease pencil made the process easier, since version 2.78 gives as one of the options of the convert button in the grease pencil tool panel, direct conversion from the grease pencil to a "polygon curve". However, I have no direct experience with trying to make that conversion.

Comment: Ok, how to  convert the edges to quad faces ?

Comment: Select the edges, and then extrude in the desired direction, and I haven't tried to use it, but the "covert to polygon curve" suggests that it might be possible to get quad faces directly.

Comment: You can't do that directly. I showcased with an image what I would like.