# Extruding equally along a path

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

This is my first post on here. I've been using Blender for years and a lot of my questions have been answered here but I've been having trouble with something and I haven't found a solution. I'm trying to create a sidewalk for a road. I figured I would do this by extruding out along both sides of the road and then extruding up. However, the road is curved, and when I got to extrude the extrusion is not equal in all directions. I've searched for a way to do this on here but I haven't found a way to equally extrude all sides. Any advice? Or is there another way to do this?

Pic is of the road object.[image]

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you perhaps show a screenshot of the issue? Maybe two part of this extrusion, side by side showing what isn't equal

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps/63322#63322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, it might work for you.

1. In Edit mode, select the first edge of your road (Left or Right) using alt-click.
2. Duplicate (Shift-D), hit Escape, then split into a new mesh (P, choose "Selection").
3. In object mode, select the new object you created (should be a single line of connected vertices), tab into edit mode, and extrude along the Z axis.  (A to select all vertices-->E to extrude-->Z to constrain to Z axis-->1 to extrude one unit-->Enter),
4. Tab into object mode then add a "solidify" modifier.  Modify the Thickness to your liking - use a positive or negative Thickness to get it to extrude out to the direction you want.
5. Apply the solidify modifier.
6. Tab into edit mode and delete the upper/lower layer of vertices, or else move them up/down to the sidewalk thickness you prefer.
7. Do the same for the other edge of your road.

Should do the trick!  At least it did with a sample curve I played with.  I don't know if it's shaped like your road.

Edit: here is a screenshot of the sample I worked with:

[image: image of road mesh with sidewalks]

I started with the light gray road mesh (which I actually created from a bezier curve), then I created the two light blue sidewalk objects using the steps described above.

Answer (score 0):

Select both edges of your road.

Press **E** to extrude, and then **Z** to constrain to the Z-axis, and drag to the height that you want your sidewalk to be and left click.

Press **E** to extrude again, then **Z** again, and type **.01** and press **Enter**

Now press **Alt+S** and drag and your sidewalk should extrude out evenly.  Left click again when your sidewalk is the width you want.(sidewalk will be slightly tilted)

Then press **G** to move the edges, **Z** to constrain to Z-axis, and type **-.01** and press **Enter**.  This will move your outer edge back down to be even with the other side of your sidewalk.