# Animated simple deform bend

Tags: animation

I'm absolutely new to Blender, and I want to animate an intro. It looks like this:

[image]

You can download the blend file here: https://github.com/bennetrr/m-lleimer/blob/871b7922073af7e66cc2ed2f0c51c22838d4cb62/intro.blend (to download click on "view raw")

I want it so, that first the circle with the red arrows gets smaller, so that it looks like on this picture:

[image]

Then, the same should happen with the green circle.

How can I animate this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg/82200#82200 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/animating-appearing-extending-strip-with-gaps/63322#63322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a plane, a curve, and array the plane along the curve with an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier:

[image]

To change the direction, select the curve, go in *Edit* mode, right click and *Switch Direction*.

Comment: thx, it worked!