# How can I create a rope knot animation in Blender that also works in Unity?

Tags: animation, workflow, unity

I want to make an animation depicting the process of making a rope knot. I tried doing it with curves, with arrays but it only works in blend when exporting to unity it all doesn’t work. I also tried with the alembic file it works perfectly but the textures are missing. Example:

[image]

What I have to do in order to make this animation also work for Unity?

Comment: look into Array + Curve modifier, see here except in your case it's a 3D object that will follow the curve: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230681/animated-simple-deform-bend/230683#230683

Comment: i try this, but is not working in unity

Comment: you can use a Curve modifier only, if you move your object it will follow all along the curve, is it possible in Unity?

Comment: i still don't get what you mean, but in unity it doesn't pick up any animation only the model, and i tried bake the animation with keyframe but it didn't work

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please add one or two screenshots to your question and describe what you have done and what you want to achieve. Your question is basically a link-only question and is not suitable for this site. If your link goes offline then all that readers in the future will know is "animation" and "unity". [Edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/230820/edit) and add details.

Comment: And while you are at it, give your question a better descriptive title. Keep in mind that your question is not only for you but should help other users that have a similar problem.

Comment: While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to 
questions they should not remain the only way to obtain information 
about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on 
downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools 
to [upload images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or 
[gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), besides 
thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be 
searched for and indexed thus helping future users find it.

Comment: I think your issue is related to Unity and not with Blender

Comment: i am looking for a suitable solution to do it easily in blender and work well in unity

Comment: In both cases (abc and fbx) you'd have to bake your textures or re-create the shader unity: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake If you'd like to use fbx, you'd have to animate the rope using bones or shapekeys, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133032/31447

Comment: Also you should specify in your question how *exactly* you want to interact with the ropes in unity. If you just want to playback the animation, you do can use a video rendered with blender and play it back at some point in time.

Comment: i tried using option 2 but when my model moves to the bend the mesh gets distorted like it's twisted

Comment: What is option 2? Part of the confusion here is how you communicate. Consider that 5 guys wrote more text in the comment section than you did in your question. Please take your time, edit your question and explain in detail what you have done and what exactly is not working, upload screenshots and ideally share a blend using https://blend-exchange.com/, also I recommend: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask